# unable to connect vs2008 to tfs2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008

Hi I have a server with tfs2013 , in my PC I've vs2008 and VS2017, all my projects are in my TFS Server, and I have no , problem when I do the connection from vs2017. I've installed "VS2008TeamExplorer.iso" too, but when I try to connect to my FTS I got the error:

[image]
I guess I need to install something else but I don't know what, does anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops#visual-studio-and-team-explorer). Visual Studio 2008 is only supported by using the [MSSCCI provider.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12128)

Comment: Thanks, I've try that too, but when I select the MSSCCI provider , and try to open the solution I got this error "This plugin is intended for older versión of visual studio. Pleas use Team Explorer" I did use the MSSCCI in other pc, the one before that I have now, the diference is: in the other pc I've installed the vs2013 team explorer and vs2015, My new one have only vs2017 , it looks like the msscci just see my vs2017 and not the vs2008